# Is WinHttpRequest.5.1 a good API for Windows 11 or does it require Iexplorer?

Tags: windows, inno-setup, ole, pascalscript, winhttprequest

I am using this code to load files during setup, is WinHttpRequest.5.1 a good API for Windows 11 or does this API have some dependencies to Internet Explorer?

```pascal
function DownloadFile(const AURL: string; var AResponse: string): Boolean;
var
  WinHttpRequest: Variant;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    WinHttpRequest := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
    WinHttpRequest.Open('GET', AURL, False);
    WinHttpRequest.Send;
    AResponse := WinHttpRequest.ResponseText;
  except
    Result := False;
    AResponse := GetExceptionMessage;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that `WinHttpRequest` has dependency on Internet Explorer. And even if it did depend on some internals of IE, I'm sure Microsoft would keep those internals to keep the `WinHttpRequest` working.

In any case, `WinHttpRequest` still works on Windows 11.

Answer (score 2):

From the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttp-versions:

> ## WinHTTP Versions
>
> 01/07/2021
>
> Users of Microsoft Windows HTTP Services (WinHTTP) should use the
> latest version of the technology, version 5.1. Version 5.0 is no
> longer supported.
>
> ### Version 5.1
>
> WinHTTP 5.1 offers improvements over version 5.0; for more information about new features, see [What's New in WinHTTP
> 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/what-s-new-in-winhttp-5-1).
>
> With version 5.1, WinHTTP **is an operating-system component** of the
> following operating systems:
>
> - **Windows 2000, Service Pack 3 and later** (except Datacenter Server)
> - Windows XP with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and later Windows Server 2003    with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and later
>
> ...

Given that it says "Windows 2000...and later" it seems clear that this is a component you can reliably use in Win11. And it has nothing to do with IE. (*)

---

(*) It sounds like according to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest) at one time IE may have been a dependency of the older 5.0 version: "*Redistributable: WinHTTP 5.0 and Internet Explorer 5.01 or later on Windows XP and Windows 2000.*"